# Thread synchronization for methods?

Tags: multithreading

how many threads will access concurrently  if the method is static synchronized and also how many threads will access concurrently if the method is static and finally how many threads will access concurrently if the method is synchronized instance method?

Answer (score 2):

- Using `static` only does not prevent any thread from accessing the method at any time
- Using `synchronized` only, the aquired monitor belongs to the object for which the method was invoked. You still can invoke the same method on other instances of the same class
- Using `static synchronized`, the aquired monitor belongs to the `class` instead to a specific object, which means that the static method can only be invoked by one thread at the same time, regardless of concrete instances

Consequence: Please note that multiple threads can concurrently invoke two synchronized methods on the same object if one of the methods is static, this could be a pitfall.

Comment: This is the correct answer, though the "consequence" might be spelled out a little more clearly: i.e. the reason more than one thread might execute concurrently is the static synchronized only stops execution by other threads attempting to run other static methods or against the class itself. Whereas the synchronized instance methods only prevent other threads running against other synchronized methods of that particular instance . The reason is that there is a Monitor for the class and Monitor for each of the instances: synchronization goes against a single monitor.